# Power BI matrix visual custom sorting

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, data-visualization, dashboard

I have a matrix visual in Power BI and need to sort it out in custom order.

The rows are sorted in the following order:

1. Function availability - Gold
2. Function availability - Lead
3. Function availability - Platinum
4. Function availability - Silver

Image for reference:
[image: Image for reference]

I want to sort it out in this order:

1. Function availability - Platinum
2. Function availability - Gold
3. Function availability - Silver
4. Function availability - Lead

Image for reference:
[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Can you show your raw sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a column where you will have the sort order. E.g.:

[image: sort order column added]

Then in Model view you can click on your column and choose the new column as the sort column:
[image: sort column added in Model view]

Then your matrix visual order will change:
[image: matrix visual sort order changed]